# Registering IdentityUser and/or IdentityRole subclasses with an OData ODataModelBuilder

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-identity

I'm having a bit of a problem integrating Identity Framework's IdentityUser and IdentityRole with my application. Here's what I'm doing with IdentityRole in particular.

I've subclassed IdentityRole in my application like so:

```
public partial class ActionRole : IdentityRole, IObjectState, ICanBeDisabledEntity, IAuditableEntity 
{
    ...
}
```

I am attempting to register 'ActionRole' as an entity set using an ODataModelBuilder:

```
public static Microsoft.Data.Edm.IEdmModel GetModel()
    {
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        ...
        builder.EntitySet<ActionRole>(typeof(ActionRole).Name);
        ...
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

However, when the application is run the `ODataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel` on the:

```
return builder.GetEdmModel();
```

method call returns the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
```

I poked around in the `System.Web.Http.OData` library and found this to be the source of the exception:

```
internal void RemoveBaseTypeProperties(IEntityTypeConfiguration derivedEntity, IEntityTypeConfiguration baseEntity)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEntityTypeConfiguration> typesToLift = new[] { derivedEntity }.Concat(this.DerivedTypes(derivedEntity));

        foreach (PropertyConfiguration property in baseEntity.Properties.Concat(baseEntity.DerivedProperties()))
        {
            foreach (IEntityTypeConfiguration entity in typesToLift)
            {
                PropertyConfiguration derivedPropertyToRemove = entity.Properties.Where(p => p.Name == property.Name).SingleOrDefault();
                if (derivedPropertyToRemove != null)
                {
                    entity.RemoveProperty(derivedPropertyToRemove.PropertyInfo);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The line `PropertyConfiguration derivedPropertyToRemove = entity.Properties.Where(p => p.Name == property.Name).SingleOrDefault();` points to my `ActionRole` entity as one that has more than one property with the same name, but I checked it and there seems to be no repetition.

Here's my ActionRole class:

```
public class ActionRole : IdentityRole, IObjectState, ICanBeDisabledEntity, IAuditableEntity 
{

    private const String CacheKey = "somekey";

    [DisplayName("Rol")]
    [InversePropertyAttribute("ActionRole")]
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Role { get; set; }

    public static string GetCacheKey(String roleName)
    {
        return CacheKey + roleName;
    }

    public ObjectState ObjectState
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public bool IsDisabled
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public string CreateUser
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public DateTime CreateTime
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public string UpdateUser
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public DateTime UpdateTime
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

}
```

I'd appreciate any insight as to why this is happening or perhaps how it can be solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, .NET Identity uses string id's as the default identifier for all its models. Because I was using an int Id field in my models there was a multiple match as a result of this statement:

```
PropertyConfiguration derivedPropertyToRemove = entity.Properties.Where(p => p.Name == property.Name).SingleOrDefault();
```

i.e. two properties with the same name but different types.

I'm in the process of switching all of the models to integer keys as per: http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/07/13/ASPNET-Identity-20-Extending-Identity-Models-and-Using-Integer-Keys-Instead-of-Strings.aspx

I'm not particularly sure as to why the .NET Identity Team decided on that course, but it represents heavy changes to my legacy applications, which I don't have the resources to complete.

That blog has been a lifesaver for me. Pretty good stuff.